# Facing Error 500.19 when add a AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, authorize-attribute

I'm trying to add a custom AuthorizeAttribute to my MVC website,i check the tutorial on web and make a simple one.

```
    public class HandAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpCookie cookieUser = httpContext.Request.Cookies["empNo"];
            if (cookieUser == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }


    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/User/Login");
        //base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

it was compiled without error but when i try to test it it show a 500.19 error on iss, showed that the web.config has problem, but when i removed the authorize attribute it was okay.
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAqD5.png)

Comment: I translated error text from the image and it said "Cannot read configuration file" - first you may check if IIS pulling old path from `.vs/config/applicationhost.config` (modify to the current path). Note that `.vs` is a hidden dir, use "show hidden files" to see it. Also check related IIS user permissions to run the app.

Comment: Addendum: In this article - [ASP. NET Error 0x80070003 (Japanese)](https://www.ipentec.com/document/document.aspx?page=visual-studio-asp-net-error-0x80070003), you can try delete .suo files and reopen the project file, it is possible to have misconfigured authorization settings.